# Как расширить имеющийся диск на ubuntu за счет другого удаленно?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, файловая-система

Можно ли расширить имеющийся диск в ubuntu?
Есть виртуальная машину куда имеется удаленный доступ через удаленный рабочий стол по root (sudo -i).

Туда добавили еще 1 диск на 1TB, интересует можно ли удаленно имея root доступ расширить корневой каталог / и не потерять данные?
Чтобы стало 1200 Гб места?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]